# Torrent DHT Node Identifier C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have created a small DHT probing application, but one of the issues I am having is that as of July nodes in the torrent DHT network [require](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0042.html) a valid identifier.

The C++ code for doing this is:

```
uint8_t* ip; // our external IPv4 or IPv6 address (network byte order)
int num_octets; // the number of octets to consider in ip (4 or 8)
uint8_t node_id[20]; // resulting node ID

uint8_t v4_mask[] = { 0x03, 0x0f, 0x3f, 0xff };
uint8_t v6_mask[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff };
uint8_t* mask = num_octets == 4 ? v4_mask : v6_mask;

for (int i = 0; i < num_octets; ++i)
    ip[i] &= mask[i];

uint32_t rand = std::rand() & 0xff;
uint8_t r = rand & 0x7;
ip[0] |= r << 5;

uint32_t crc = 0;
crc = crc32c(crc, ip, num_octets);

// only take the top 21 bits from crc
node_id[0] = (crc >> 24) & 0xff;
node_id[1] = (crc >> 16) & 0xff;
node_id[2] = ((crc >> 8) & 0xf8) | (std::rand() & 0x7);
for (int i = 3; i < 19; ++i) node_id[i] = std::rand();
node_id[19] = rand;
```

I have implemented the CRC32C and that works, but I can't replicate the test vectors from the [article](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0042.html).

My code (C#):

```
public static byte[] GenerateNodeIDValid(byte[] ipBytes, byte randValue = 0)
   {
       byte[] tempBytes = ipBytes; // An editable container for our IP bytes. (Should be four bytes for IPv4)
       byte[] node_id_bytes = new byte[20]; // A container for the final assembled ID.
       byte[] ipV4MaskBytes = {3, 15, 63, 255}; // A mask for the IP.

       // To create a valid IP Prefix:
       // crc32c((ip & 0x030f3fff) | (r << 29))
       // r is a random number in the range [0, 7]. 
       // The resulting integer, representing the masked IP address is supposed to be
       // big-endian before hashed. The "|" operator means bit-wise OR.


       // Step 1. Mask the bytes.
       for (int i = 0; i < tempBytes.Count(); i++)
       {
           tempBytes[i] &= ipV4MaskBytes[i]; // This equals: tempBytes[i] = tempBytes[i] & ipV4MaskBytes[i];
       }

       // Step 2. Generate the random initialize vector.
       Random random = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(ipBytes,0)); // Generate a new seed from our IP address.
       byte r;
       if (randValue!=0)
       {
           r = randValue;
       }
       else
       {
           r = (byte) random.Next(0, 7); // Should be a byte 
       }          

       // Step 3. Generate the CRC32C for our IP in Big Little Endian Format.
       ipBytes[0] |= (byte) (r << 5); // TODO: Calculate The order.

       byte[] crc = BitConverter.GetBytes(CRC32C.Compute(tempBytes)); // Converts uint to byte[].
       // Console.WriteLine("CRC: {0}",Hex.ToString(crc)); Works.


       node_id_bytes[0] =(byte) (crc[0] & 0xff);
       node_id_bytes[1] =(byte) (crc[1] & 0xff);
       node_id_bytes[2] =(byte) ((crc[2] & 0xf8) | r & 0x7) ;

      RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
      byte[] byteData = new byte[17];
       rng.GetNonZeroBytes(byteData); // Generate the rest of the bytes
       Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData,0,node_id_bytes,3,17); // Fill the node_ID_Bytes with the rest of the information.


       return node_id_bytes;
   }
```

Instead of

```
5fbfbf f10c5d6a4ec8a88e4c6ab4c28b95eee4 01
5a3ce9 c14e7a08645677bbd1cfe7d8f956d532 56
a5d432 20bc8f112a3d426c84764f8c2a1150e6 16
1b0321 dd1bb1fe518101ceef99462b947a01ff 41
e56f6c bf5b7c4be0237986d5243b87aa6d5130 5a
```

I get:

```
1243175219F5889D7509CCA1B6B2D2BC193BE85375E376249
217531124F27126AEC277487D4D83B1F81AF6648BA627AA44
652351170135AD6F4BD63519BB953CA82084EAC36265314E2
841247314A762394E97D174BE1E5EABFBCBA95F906F947BBD
43213538343FA8241C1B41D8F7CEE89C560E692207B7416D4
```

Which leads me to believe there is an issue with the masking, any help would be appreciated.